# Error NU5026 dll to be packed was not found

Tags: .net, github, yaml, nuget, github-actions

I am getting following error :

```
create_nuget
The file '/home/runner/work/MyNugetPackage/MyNugetPackage/MyNugetPackage/bin/Release/net6.0/MyNugetPackage.dll' to be packed was not found on disk.
```

This is my YAML file :

```
name: publish   
on:
  workflow_dispatch: # Allow running the workflow manually from the GitHub UI
  push:
    branches:
      - 'master'       # Run the workflow when pushing to the main branch
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - '*'          # Run the workflow for all pull requests
  release:
    types:
      - published    # Run the workflow when a new GitHub release is published

env:
  DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE: 1
  DOTNET_NOLOGO: true
  NuGetDirectory: ${{ github.workspace }}/nuget

defaults:
  run:
    shell: pwsh

jobs:
  debug:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: List files
      run: ls -R

  create_nuget:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with:
        fetch-depth: 0 # Get all history to allow automatic versioning using MinVer

    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3

    - run: dotnet pack --configuration Release --output ${{ env.NuGetDirectory }}

    - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: nuget
        if-no-files-found: error
        retention-days: 7
        path: ${{ env.NuGetDirectory }}/*.nupkg

  validate_nuget:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [create_nuget]
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3

    - uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: nuget
        path: ${{ env.NuGetDirectory }}

    - name: Install nuget validator
      run: dotnet tool update Meziantou.Framework.NuGetPackageValidation.Tool --global

    - name: Validate package
      run: meziantou.validate-nuget-package (Get-ChildItem "${{ env.NuGetDirectory }}/*.nupkg")

  run_test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
    - name: Run tests
      run: dotnet test --configuration Release

  deploy:
    if: github.event_name == 'release'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [validate_nuget, run_test]
    steps:
    - uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: nuget
        path: ${{ env.NuGetDirectory }}

    - name: Setup .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3

    - name: Publish NuGet package
      run: |
        foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem "${{ env.NuGetDirectory }}" -Recurse -Include *.nupkg)) {
          dotnet nuget push $file --api-key "${{ secrets.NUGET_APIKEY }}" --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json --skip-duplicate
        }
```

I have tried to run command to generate release folder as well in local because it was earlier complaining about it but now it is failing , I am using GitHub actions.

It is a Nuget packages that is supposed to be compatible with .NET 6

I am not sure what am I missing here.

Comment: Is this path `/home/runner/work/MyNugetPackage/MyNugetPackage/MyNugetPackage/bin/Release/net6.0/MyNugetPackage.dll` valid? Have you checked the build logs? Is that DLL being generated? If yes, include those logs in your question.

Comment: Yes this is exact error generated by Github Actions

Comment: Have you looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu5026 and ruled out all the potential causes mentioned here?

Answer (score 0):

Encountered similar issue. There is a thing in your csproj that may trigger that. Make sure to remove this:

```xml
<GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
```

[source](https://steveellwoodnlc.medium.com/error-nu5026-the-file-to-be-packed-was-not-found-on-disk-18bfbc6be4a)

The error line (french) was:

NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(221,5): error NU5026: Le fichier 'C:...\bin\Release\net48....dll' à compresser est introuvable sur le disque.